# Matlab: if a=40*1 and b=32*1 how to build c=40*32?

Tags: matlab

I want to know in matlab how to calculate this: **`a=40*1` and `b=32*1` how to build `c=40*32`?**

Comment: Do you mean that `a` is a 40x1 matrix, and `b` is a 32x1 matrix? There are many ways to combine them to yield a 40x32 matrix. You have to decide what arithmetic operation you want to do for `c(i,j) = a(i) x b(j)`. The `x` can be addition or multiplication, or many other things.

Comment: you could have tried .... `a*b'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Cris Luengo is correct and

1. **A** is a [matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) of dimension 40x1 (a [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(mathematics_and_physics)))
2. **B** is a matrix of dimension 32x1 (another vector)

Then you can generate a matrix, using @bla's idea:

**C** = **A** **B**^T

which in MATLAB's notation would be
`c = a*b.'` The resulting dimension of **C** would be 40x32, because dimensionwise (40x1)(1x32) = 40x32.

where **B**^T is the [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose). See this [example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%7D%2C%7B2%7D%2C%7B3%7D%7D*transpose%28%7B%7B3%7D%2C%7B4%7D%2C%7B5%7D%2C%20%7B6%7D%7D%29) with two vectors of dimension 3x1 and 4x1, where the resulting matrix is of dimension 3x4.

Comment: May be you should use the correct shorthand notation for `transpose(b)` which is `b.'`. The current symbol you used `b'` is a shorthand for `Complex Conjugate`. Both operations yields the same result on non-complex vectors (so it's ok for this example), but with complex numbers in input the results would be quite different. Sorry for being pedantic, but I think it is better to give correct instructions to beginners or it may confuse them later down the line.